# Compatibility issues between typedefs

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, typedef

I am using `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` to prevent misuses of different string-based ID types. I am however running into compatibility problems between the original type and its typedef.

I have an `std::string` which contains a list of IDs, separated by commas. I need to store them into a set. The code would look like:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/strong_typedef.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>

#include <set>
#include <vector>

BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(std::string, MY_ID)

int main()
{
    std::string line("ID1,ID2,ID3");

    // Use boost::split to get all the strings into a vector
    std::vector<std::string> id_vec;
    boost::split(id_vec, line, boost::is_any_of(","));

    // Generate a set of MY_ID. Do not use range constructor since the compiler
    // error is clearer this way
    std::set<MY_ID> ids;
    for (auto const & id : id_vec)
    {
        ids.insert(id);
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile, since `std::string` cannot be inserted into a `std::set<MY_ID>`. However, if I declared the vector to be of type `std::vector<MY_ID>` it would not work with `boost::split`.

I have found a work around by adding a temporal variable when inserting:

```
for (auto const & id : id_vec)
{
    MY_ID tmp(id);
    ids.insert(tmp);
}
```

This works but seems hacky. Is there a more concise way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of strong typedefs is to require an explicit conversion when creating the strong typedef out of its underlying type. So use an explicit conversion syntax:

```
for (auto const & id : id_vec)
{
    ids.insert(MY_ID{id});
}
```

Alternative ways to do the conversion are `static_cast<MY_ID>(id)` and `MY_ID(id)` (note that the latter is equivalent to the C-style cast `(MY_ID)id` and is thus best avoided).

Comment: Thank you very much, I wasn't aware of this C++11 feature :)

Comment: @user2891462 The C++98 way would be to use `()` instead of `{}`, but it can be less safe. Or just use `static_cast<MY_ID>(id)`.

Comment: Oh! I am surprised, I do remember trying `static_cast<>` and it not working. I have double checked and it does, so there was probably something else going on in the original code. This seems like a trivial question now!

Comment: @user2891462 Most questions are trivial once you know the answer. A.k.a. [the "It's obvious" joke](http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?p=143064&sid=d2195cf9e59ceb93377e22e4216135ae#p143064).